# How do I open an .eml file in Evolution?

Tags: evolution, mail, ms-exchange

Open EML extension mail file in evolution.if anybody sent mail from outook to evolution not able to open the file please help

Answer (score 2):

Evolution will not display such thing inline, and it will rely on the environment to open the file. Try downloading the file outside of Evolution. That should present you with a dialog where you can choose which application should handle that file type. Evolution should then use that application to open it.

Comment: It will of great help if you can name the software